# Kali linux tool fluxion: are you able to alter or edit fluxion's fake access point page?

Tags: penetration-testing

So i recently taken up testing and came across this tool called fluxion --mostly used for intercepting WiFi passwords. Well Fluxion creates a fake access point tricking users to  enter their password into a fake login page. Well curiosity hit me almost instantly; are you able to alter the page to make it more believable using html/css or js?

Thank u guys

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to alter a webpage instead of just asking a wpa/wpa2 key
you can use fsociety tool for it
clone the tool using :
clone git https://github.com/Manisso/fsociety

and VIOLA! you can use Fsociety and it might help you